# Singleton – extra script not destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have a singleton which will store, update and show player score through all levels (scenes), but something works wrong.

This my singletone script GameStatus.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class GameStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameStatus instance;

    [SerializeField] int pointsPerBlock = 50;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;

    [SerializeField] public static int currentScore = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
    public void AddToScore()
    {
        currentScore += pointsPerBlock;
        scoreText.text = currentScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

I also have another script for objects player need to destroy, called Block.cs. Here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Block : MonoBehaviour
{
    Level level;
    GameStatus gameStatus;

    private void Start()
    {
        level = FindObjectOfType<Level>();
        gameStatus = FindObjectOfType<GameStatus>();

        level.CountBreakableBlocks();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        DestroyBlock();
    }

    private void DestroyBlock()
    {
        level.BlockDestroyed();
        gameStatus.AddToScore();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

And on level 1 everything works fine, but when the game goes to the next level this happens:

1. Player score stops updating.
2. If I use *Debug.Log(currentScore);* in GameStatus.cs I can see that this variable doesn't change when player breaks blocks, but if use *Debug.Log(gameStatus.currentScore);* in Block.cs then I can see that this variable is getting updated.
3. *Debug.Log(FindObjectsOfType().Length);* shows that there is one GameStatus object in the first level and two objects in the next levels, although I can't see the second one GameStatus in hierarchy.

**So my question is - what's wrong and how to fix it?**

Comment: Please don't add the solution as edit to your question. Either accept one of the given answers or post your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use singleton, there is no point to make

```
currentScore
```

static variable, just make it

```
public int currentScore;
```

Also in your block cs you can just call

```
GameStatus.instance.AddToScore();
```

No need to make reference at start